# Two levels nested models in active admin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I am able to accept nested attributes of a has many relationship in active admin, but is it possible to nest two levels?

I mean, i have a model lesson, which has many chapters, and the chapters have many sections. Is it possible to create chapters and their sections all in the lessons tab?
How? My model lesson accepts nested attributes for chapters and chapters accept nested attributes for sections

I am using ror3 and last version of active admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I should recommend you to check it out the [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/) it's very straight forward to implement it and you can nest as many forms as you need it. Also it it has support for SimpleForm and Formtastic.

[Here](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2010/12/31/dynamically-nesting-deeply-nested-forms.html) you could find an example where explains a 4 level nested form.